# Magento reindex issues in enterprise edition

Tags: php, magento

How to manually re-index in **magento ee 1.13.0.2** for "Stock Status" and "Catalog product price"?

Actually I have tried with

```
$process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
$process->reindexAll();
```

but it didn't result in what I expected.

Comment: maybe you can reindex use shell command?

Answer (score 3):

I've stumbled upon this myself few days ago. Indexes have been reworked drastically in EE, that's why old style reindexing doesn't work. You can't reindex at will anymore, instead you could schedule your reindex so the next cron job will do it for you in the background:

```
$client = Mage::getModel('enterprise_mview/client');
$client->init('catalog_product_index_price');
$metadata = $client->getMetadata();
$metadata->setInvalidStatus();
$metadata->save();
```

Explanation on the new indexing system: http://www.eschrade.com/page/indexing-in-magento-or-the-wonderful-world-of-materialized-views/

Comment: Technically, if the cron-job is able to do a full re-index, there is some code in the Magento 1 API that can this as well. Just saying, what you answer here is correct that there normally isn't a full-reindex (necessary) any longer in EE and the MySql triggers should automatically take care of that (in conjunction with the always cron).

Answer (score -2):

```
$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessById(2);

$process = Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_product_price');
```

or try `$process->reindexEverything();`

```
Process Name        ID          Code
Product Attributes      1       catalog_product_attribute
Product Prices          2       catalog_product_price
Catalog URL Rewrites    3       catalog_url
Product Flat Data       4       catalog_product_flat
Category Flat Data      5       catalog_category_flat
Category Products       6       catalog_category_product
Catalog Search Index    7       catalogsearch_stock
Stock Status            8       cataloginventory_stock
Tag Aggregation Data    9       tag_summary
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, i have tried with this code also but in EE 1.13.0.2 its not working.

Answer (score -2):

In magetno 1.13.0.2 Reindex will done automaticly by MySQL triggers.
Only that you need - setup cronjob for magento.

For test it, you can run http://yousite.com/cron.php manually